# Angular Currency Pipe Symbol not available for GYD (Guyana Dollar), How can I configure the Symbols in App.module?

Tags: angular, pipe, currency

```
 <h1> My rate is : {{'202' | currency:'GYD'}}</h1>`
```

Current Output is : GYD 202

Expected Ouput is GY$ 202

Answer (score 1):

Angular's currency pipe relies on the Internationalization API to format currencies. The currency symbol used is based on the current locale configured in the application.

You can configure the currency symbol for GYD in the 'AppModule':

Here are rudimentary steps you can take:

1. Import LOCALE_ID from @angular/core,
2. Provide the custom locale ID and the currency symbol.
3. In your component, use the currency pipe as usual.

Short code example:

```
import { NgModule, LOCALE_ID } from '@angular/core';
import { registerLocaleData } from '@angular/common';
import localeGYD from '@angular/common/locales/en-GYD';

@NgModule({
  // ...
  providers: [
    // Provide the custom locale ID and the currency symbol for GYD
    { provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: 'en-GYD' },
    { provide: 'currencyCode', useValue: 'GYD' },
    { provide: 'currencySymbol', useValue: 'GY$' },
  ],
})
export class AppModule {
  constructor() {
    // Register the GYD locale data
    registerLocaleData(localeGYD, 'en-GYD');
  }
}
```

Here is a working [stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-5wsor3?file=src%2Fmain.ts).

Comment: In this Case,Can I Write this Without a new Pipe?
I am getting error in this Line
import localeGYD from '@angular/common/locales/en-GYD';

Thnks bro..

Comment: If you're getting an error, then using the custom pipe is the solution because it does not use that import! @DineshKanivu

Comment: locales/en-GYD. instead locales/en-GY Its works without Error

Comment: I am glad you were able to figure it out! I hope I was helpful. :)